# How to implement selectable list for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, singleton, factory, observablecollection

What seemed to be a simple problem has puzzled me for a while so I'd appreciate some advice.

I need to implement selectable list for use in WPF. Since list can be very long and user would normally select only few items I was thinking the best approach would be to get complete list only once and then just list of selected objects for every instance of my main object (MyParent). MyParent could also be instantiated many times and user normally works with multiple instances at once. I want user to be able to see entire list with possible items and be able to select what they want. I'm not sure how to make bindings to such properties

My code (simplified and names generalized):

```
// item model:
public class MyItem
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
}

// items factory (ideally entire list should only be
// pulled once in a program lifetime hence singleton):
public class MyItemsFactory
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> myItems => new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
    public static ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems => Instance.myItems;

    private MyItemsFactory()
    {
        GetItems();
    }
    private void GetItems()
    {
        // generate some sample data
        var i1 = new MyItem() { ItemId = 1, ItemName = "Item 1" };
        var i2 = new MyItem() { ItemId = 2, ItemName = "Item 2" };
        var i3 = new MyItem() { ItemId = 3, ItemName = "Item 3" };
        var i4 = new MyItem() { ItemId = 4, ItemName = "Item 4" };
        myItems.Add(i1);
        myItems.Add(i2);
        myItems.Add(i3);
        myItems.Add(i4);
    }

    #region Singleton Implementation
    private static readonly Lazy<MyItemsFactory> instance = new Lazy<MyItemsFactory>(() => new MyItemsFactory());
    public static MyItemsFactory Instance => instance.Value;
    #endregion
}

// parent class
public class MyParent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MySelectedItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
    public MyParent()
    {
        GetSelectedItems();
    }
    private void GetSelectedItems()
    {
        // generate some sample data
        var si2 = new MyItem() { ItemId = 2, ItemName = "Item 2", IsSelected = true };
        var si4 = new MyItem() { ItemId = 4, ItemName = "Item 4", IsSelected = true };
        MySelectedItems.Add(si2);
        MySelectedItems.Add(si4);
        // how to include remaining MyItemsFactory.MyItems here?
    }
}
```

my UserControl:

```
<!-- DataContext is set to one of the instance of MyParent -->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MySelectedItems}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Selected">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ToggleButton
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                            Content="Selected"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Item Name">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ToggleButton Content="Selected"
                                        IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                        Command="{x:Static c:CommandManager.SelectItem}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This works fine but of course displays only MySelectedItems. My intention is to display all items (from MyItemsFactory.MyItems for example) with selected items according to MySelectedItems of MyParent instance. Many thanks.

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here. Why are you trying to maintain a list of the currently selected items? Each item already has a `IsSelected` property, which will be updated when the user toggles the buttons. Just bind your ItemsControl ItemsSource to MyItems so that you see all of them.

Comment: What's wrong with binding ItemsSource to MyItems, and SelectedItems to MySelectedItems?

Comment: Expose `MyItemsFactory.MyItems` via a property on `MyParent`.

Comment: @MarkFeldman If I do that every instance of MyParent would have identical list of MyItems

Comment: @RobinBennett I have not checked that tbh. I assumed it would not work since items in MyItems and MySelectedItems point to different objects (for example si2 != i2)

Comment: Ah, good point, any objects in SelectedItems needs to also be in Items, not just have the same properties.

Answer (score 0):

Expose the singleton set of all items in `MyParent`:

```
public class MyParent
{
    public MyItems 
    {
        get
        {
            return MyItemsFactory.MyItems;
        }
    }
}
```

ListView can then be bound to that property:

```
<!-- DataContext is set to one of the instance of MyParent -->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
...
```

Comment: Wouldn't every instance of MyParent point to same collection (since it is singleton) and selected items in it? I have to have same base collection in every instance of MyParent but selected items in that collection could be different.

Comment: All `MyParent`'s would point to your singleton `MyItemsFactory` and the `MyItems` within because you said you want to share those. Each `MyParent` would have its own "collection of selected items" - a variable subset of `MyItems`. My example doesn't include the code you already have - i.e. `MySelectedItems` - that would still be there (although I also agree with Mark that you should use the `IsSelected` property of the items, not a separate collection to define "selected items").

Comment: If you're still not sure how to differentiate between "all items" and "selected items" at the same time in the DataContext/ViewModel then please say so and I can probably add more to my answer to clarify. I thought you just wanted to know how to get the singleton collection of MyItems into the ListView but perhaps you're not sure how to have the separate collections.

Comment: I'm sorry if I confused you. I see how `IsSelected` property in `MyItems` is misleading, I would probably like to remove it from the model. I guess my rephrased question is now whether I'm correctly making `MySelectedItems` subset so @RobinBennett suggestion would work? ListView does not seem to expose SelectedItems property I could bind `MySelectedItems` to.

Comment: I've had problems with SelectedItems not being bindable in DataGrid - maybe it's a problem for ListView too (I don't know off hand). I resorted to event handling in the View code-behind to get around that for DataGrid. If you can't bind ListView.SelectedItems to a SelectedItems in your DataContext then you might need to workaround it too. Try searching "binding ListView SelectedItems". Sorry I wasn't more helpful. :)